# Equal convergence of a function

Tags: calculus

so I have to check if $ f(x)=\frac{nx}{n+x+1} $ equal convergent in $[0;1]$.I proved that $f_{n+1} \ge f_{n}$ but also I found it is true $n+x+1\ge nx$ then it is decreasing and a bound exists thus is it equally convergent?

Comment: What does "equally convergent" mean?

Comment: From *M.Staniszewski*: We say that a
sequence ($f_n$) is equally convergent to $f$ if there exists a sequence of positive reals
($\epsilon_n$) $\rightarrow$ 0 such that for every $x \in X$ there is $N$ with $|f_n(x) − f_(x)| < \epsilon n$ for every
$n > N$.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

$$\left|\frac{nx}{n+x+1} - x\right|= \frac{x(x+1)}{n+x+1} \leqslant\frac{2}{n+1}$$